# Using beforeSend and complete in every instance of ajaxForm globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I am trying to use the beforeSend and complete functions on all ajaxForms in a project. I would like to do this without adding the exact bit a code all throughout the project.

I've been able to accomplish this with the below code on a per form basis.

```
           beforeSend: function() {
                $('.lightbox').append('<div id="page-loader" style="display:block"><div class="page-loader-overlay"></div><div class="page-loader-content-container"><div class="top-corners"><div></div></div><div class="middle"><div class="page-loader-content">Loading...</div></div><div class="bottom-corners"><div></div></div></div></div>');
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                $('.lightbox#page-loader').remove()
            },
```

I'd like to be able to put that code into one place that executes every time an ajaxForm is submitted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.lightbox').append('<div id="page-loader" style="display:block"><div class="page-loader-overlay"></div><div class="page-loader-content-container"><div class="top-corners"><div></div></div><div class="middle"><div class="page-loader-content">Loading...</div></div><div class="bottom-corners"><div></div></div></div></div>');
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            $('.lightbox#page-loader').remove()
        },  
    });
});
```

Please use the function ajaxsetup. When you do it this way it will be valid in all ajax functions.

**Referrer :** https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs across a similar dilemma, this is what I came up with and it seems to do the trick. I haven't found any problems with this thus far.

```
// add loading masks on form submits
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
    $('.lightbox').append('<div id="page-loader" style="display:block; z-index: 999"><div class="page-loader-overlay"></div><div class="page-loader-content-container"><div class="top-corners"><div></div></div><div class="middle"><div class="page-loader-content">Loading...</div></div><div class="bottom-corners"><div></div></div></div></div>');
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $('#page-loader').remove()
});
```

Comment: The problem I see is that you have to be 100% sure thal all ajax calls will run this code. If you add somethig later you might have issues.

Comment: That's a good point @DaniloKörber. Preferably I'd only tap into the ajaxForm calls.